# Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process (Sublime Text)

Tags: gruntjs, sublimetext2, grunt-contrib-watch

When using Sublime Text to save a file that is being watched by Grunt - I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process

I've been reading other posts which have said that I need to remove the Livereload package.
However, I never installed the Livereload package.

Further more, if I change the port number in the `Gruntfile.js` - then restart grunt server

- I am still receiving the same error (only with the reassigned port).
  No matter what I do
- I can't get rid of this error.

I even tried deleting and reinstalling Sublime Text 2.
The error does not occur with other Editors (XCode for example).
This error has even led me to quit Sublime all together and switch over to TextMate.

Typing this in Terminal: `lsof | grep 35729`
yields no output.

After I switched from Sublime to Textmate, the problem disappeared - but a few hours later it has returned. Really lost on this one.

Comment: Any chance sublime tries to run second grunt copy? For "build on save" for example. It's not a out-of-the-box feature, but afaik it's possible.

Comment: Well, I don't know. The only thing I can suggest is to disable installed packages one by one until error is gone.

Comment: But this happens on a fresh Sublime Text 2 install

Comment: You can see what is using the port with `lsof | grep 35729` Here is a good issue for debugging this same problem: https://github.com/toddmotto/fireshell/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

Any instance of Livereload (other than in the Gruntfile.js) will be using the same port 35729.

The probable ones are:

- firefox add-on or chrome extension  of Live reload.
- The live reload app itself.
- Live reload as a Sublime package.

Try uninstalling them(or you can just simply close them) and run "grunt serve".